# svn on ubuntu: SSLhandshake failed

Tags: svn, ubuntu

`svn: OPTIONS of 'https://comp20006.eng.unimelb.edu.au/svn/pochen': SSL handshake failed: Secure connection truncated (https://comp20006.eng.unimelb.edu.au)`

Hi all, thanks for having a look at this question.

I was using ubuntu 11.10 when I tried to check out my stuff from my university server.
Would that be a problem of ubuntu or the server or any other possible things?
And how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a discussion about the problem http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1511387

Comment: I can't simply close one question, can I? I used scp instead of svn checkout at that time.. Do I have to accept one answer?

Comment: if no answer solves your problem - you don't have to.

Comment: I was facing this exact same problem. After some additional research I discovered that you can see this error as a result of SSLstrip, which our work employs.

Answer (score 2):

One fine morning i found that my svn update or svn up was not working and was totally blank? :P

Here is what i did to make my svn stand up... :)

```
  1. sudo apt-get install libneon27

  2. cd /usr/lib

  3. sudo rm libneon-gnutls.so.27

  4. and create a soft link 
       sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27 libneon-gnutls.so.27
```

and finally i started to rock :)

Comment: thanks, I did that as well but didn't work. My tutor said it was the university's problem. so I don't bother this any more. Thank you anyway.

Comment: This used to work with 11.10 Oneiric, but in 12.04 Precise these libs are not interchangeable anymore.

Comment: The error "Secure connection truncated" indicates completely different issue.

Comment: Works fine for Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS...+1

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your connection

```
openssl s_client -connect mysvnserver.org:443
```

This will give you a log of information about each step of the handshake, and the --debug option will show even more detail. It'll complain about having an invalid cert, bad time, or only outdated algorithms.

Of course, make sure you can even ping it and that https isn't firewalled off for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in 12.04 using these instructions:

http://www.yeap.de/blog2.0/archives/260-Subversion-Certificate-Problems-with-Ubuntu-Precise-Pangolin.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a [problem of multiple virtual hosts using SSL](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm) on the same machine. It caused SVN to use a different SSL certificate than expected. What I did was I renamed the subversion.conf file to 00-subversion.conf (Apache 2.4 style...). This made Apache use Subversion certificate first and other certificates for other applications went afterwards (which is OK - contemporary browsers have no problem with that unlike some SVN clients).